# Video_player could not find exoplayer, error with Gradle

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm new to Flutter and am trying to make a simple test of the Video_Player package. However when I try to run this set up on the Android Emulator & also when I run it on an Android Device (works fine on IOS) it fails with this error message:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

> Could not find com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.8.0.

Edit: I noticed that this error occurs during the Gradle build:
BUILD FAILED in 2s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Here's my code taken from a Flutter Youtube demo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Video Example',
        home: VideoExample(),
      );
    }
}

class VideoExample extends StatefulWidget {

  VideoState createState() => VideoState();
}

class VideoState extends State<VideoExample> {
 VideoPlayerController playerController;
 VoidCallback listener;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    listener = () {
      setState(() {});
    };
  }

  void createVideo() {
    if (playerController == null) {
      playerController =
          VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/videos/PilatesTestOverview.mp4')
            ..addListener(listener)
            ..setVolume(1.0)
            ..initialize();
    }
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Video Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          child: Container(
            child: (playerController != null
            ? VideoPlayer(playerController)
            : Container()),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          createVideo();
          playerController.play();
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And my Pubsepc.Yaml package dependency:

video_player: ^0.7.2

Please let me know if I am missing something here. Any help gratefully appreciated, as I haven't been able to find any fixes online.
Cheers

Comment: See also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25145 for a temporary workaround see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25145#issuecomment-445854570

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Günter has already  added the details of the dependency issue ,another **workaround** that I can suggest which I have tested is modifying the dependency to the working version in pubspec (I have tested this and seems to be fine):

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  video_player: ^0.5.1
```

I would like to append the solution from github issues page ( credits: github user pupali , https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25145#issuecomment-445854570) for completeness sake

update the build.gradle in the android folder with this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks guys. For reference, I tried all the different solutions that were suggested in 25145, however still received the error. The set up as described above though does thankfully solve the error.

Comment: Not worked for me. Its still shows error - E/flutter (15119): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, null, -1, null, [720, 1428, -1.0], [-1, -1]), null, null)