# Flutter isn't playing video on release mode

Tags: android, flutter, exception, video, video-player

I'm using the video_player package in Flutter to play some videos from a API.
When i run the app on debug mode, it works just fine, but when i try it out in release mode, (since i neeed to generate an apk for other peoples to try it out, so i also test the app in release mode) the video simply doesn't play. The terminal throws an error that is:

```
E/flutter (19035): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error c.b.a.a.j0: Source error, null, null)
```

The problem is, i search this error on google and it simply says that it didn't find any article on the web to help me out. Please, can someone help me? I really need this to work just fine.

Comment: Did you add internet permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` on the manifest file?

Comment: yep, o did. I did it to make some http requests for my app

Comment: You can checkout this package named [chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie) that handle most of the work for you. Follow the guide [here](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/video-player-in-flutter-22202be72d6e)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715910/video-player-could-not-find-exoplayer-error-with-gradle

Comment: i set those configurations to my build.gradle and it didn't work either

Comment: I used chewie and it still prints the same error and the video doesn't player

Answer (score 1):

check if you have added internet permission inside manifest file of android and make sure the url starts with **https** than **http** when running in release mode .

Answer (score 1):

I am also getting the same error, and found that video_player plugin need **HTTPS** URLs to play video in release version and i am using HTTP URL.
HTTP URL will only work in debug mode and will not work in release mode